# JavaScript's onmouseout event not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, onmouseout

I'm having a problem with the `onmouseout` event when used in a dynamically created HTML element.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="imageWrapper">
    <img src="imageUrl" alt="">
</div>
```

This is -part of- the JavaScript code (using [jQuery 1.7.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/21/jquery-1-7-2-released/)):

```
$('body').on('mouseout', 'div#imageWrapper', function () {
    alert("Test");
});
```

Clearly, what I want is to detect when the mouse leaves the `div#imageWrapper` and display an alert message.

And it works, but not as I expected it to work:

When the mouse leaves the `div#imageWrapper` it does displays the alert, but when inside the `div` the mouse goes over the `img` element, it displays it too (as if the `img` element was "an outside part of" the `div`). The weird thing is that when the mouse leaves the image (but the mouse remains on the `div`), it too displays the alert message.

**Bottom line:** JavaScript is treating both the `div#imageWrapper` and the `img` element inside it as two distinct `div#imageWrapper`s.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead:

```
$('body').on('mouseleave', 'div#imageWrapper', function () {
    alert("Test");
});
```

Comment: Lol, that was easy. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can